# Defining functions in derived classes

Tags: c++, subclass, virtual-functions, base-class

Suppose I have one base class fruit and three derived classes say Apple,orange and mango.Now I want to define one member function "taste" in Apple class only.So how can I do that?
Is it necessary to define it in base class and all the derived classes Or I can define it in only one desired class i.e. apple
Do I have to use virtual function for that

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to define it in base class. However, you will not be able to call this method on base class pointer or reference though. The function doesn't need to be virtual.

```
class Fruit {};
class Apple : public Fruit
{
public:
    void Taste();
}

class Orange : public Fruit {}
class Mango : public Fruit {}

Fruit* f = new Apple();
f->Taste(); // Error
Apple* a = new Apple();
a->Taste() // Ok
```

If however you want to have access to the method from base class pointer or reference, you need to define a empty implementation of a virtual method in base class and override it in Apple class.

```
class Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void Taste() {}
};
class Apple : public Fruit
{
public:
    virtual void Taste()
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}

class Orange : public Fruit {}
class Mango : public Fruit {}

Fruit* f = new Apple();
f->Taste(); // Ok
Fruit* f2 = new Orange();
f2->Taste(); // Ok and no side effect.
```

Comment: Then how to call this method from derived class.Actually I want to call this method on base class pointer but at the same time I don't want to include it in every derived class due to very large size of code

Comment: Apple a; a.Taste(); If you define it empty in base, you don't have to redefine it in every inherited classes unless you want to change the default implementation like in Apple. Look at my second example

Comment: Fruit should be pure virtual, it feels better that way.

`virtual void Taste() = 0;`

Comment: @Roger Rabbit I agree but the requirement is to not have it in every inherited class.

Comment: than look at my answer below, you can define Taste as a class (it explained fully in the answer), and in each case you need a "Taste"

you just add the "Taste" class

Comment: @Eric Fortin But if we declare the method in base class then doesn't it becomes ,by default,the method of each base class.I want to have it only in one derived class and not in every class and want to have access to the method from base class pointer or reference

Comment: @user3374548 Then there is no way that I know to do that. If you want it from base class, it has to be declared there unless you want to resort to some introspectable component architecture(which would still use some form of virtual methods for the component part). This is a lot of work in C++ since the language does not support that out of the box.

Comment: @Eric Fortran.Also,according to your example 2,Taste method defined as virtual in base class, becomes the method of each derived class and if we define it in only one class say Apple then it creates error as we have not defined in other derived classes.Please correct me ,if I am wrong

Comment: Your question is tagged C++ and I don't know any way in C++ to do this with the language only. And for my second example, it will compile without error as the inheriting classes are ... inheriting base call method implementation but they have the ability to overwrite them.

Answer (score 0):

in general design pattern that class behavior and qualities should be added as a pattern, in a different sub class called taset.

this is a good example for ducks, this apply for your fruit as well

http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/5448/f09/lectures/16-introdesignpatterns.pdf